# Hide an entity variable from xml message - @XmlTransient not working

Tags: java, xml, web-services, jaxb, xmltransient

I have an entity class:

```
public class Customer implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@XmlTransient
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "CUSTOMER_ID")
private Integer customerId;
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Size(min = 1, max = 30)
@Column(name = "NAME")
private String name;
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Size(min = 1, max = 30)
@Column(name = "ADDRESSLINE1")
private String addressline1;
@Basic(optional = false)
.
.
.
.
```

I sent an object of the class via xml in jax-ws web service like so:

```
<addressline1>xx</addressline1><addressline2>xx</addressline2><city>xx</city><country>xx</country><creditLimit>xx</creditLimit><customerId>xx</customerId><email>xx</email><name>xx</name><owner>xx</owner><phone>xx</phone><province>xx</province><zip>xx</zip>
```

Is it possible to not sent one of the variables such as customerId, which the client shouldn't see?
I have added @XmlTransient, but no change.

Answer (score 23):

By default public properties are serialized to XML.  You will need to mark the corresponding `get` method `@XmlTransient`.  If you wish to a annotate the fields you can add the following to your class `@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)`.

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/04/jaxb-and-unmapped-properties.html
- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/06/using-jaxbs-xmlaccessortype-to.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply, worked nicely. These little things are hard to find.

Answer (score 1):

Tried with `@XmlTransient` in different combinations with `@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)`, on my machine it did not work.

What did work for me, to hide functions, was to annotate each function with `@WebMethod(exclude = true)`, to hide it from the `wsdl` and thereby exposure to the client.