# Many-to-many relation returns empty collection

Tags: java, rest, jakarta-ee

I am trying to create two entities which have many-to-many relation between them. First entity is **Person** with **PID** as primary key, second is **Serie** with **SID** as primary key. In database there is a table **TJV_5_SERIE_2_PERSON**, which represents many to many relationship between these entities.

[tables in database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/91mqg.jpg)

The problem is when I retrieve any entity, Collection annotated with @ManyToMany is always empty. So I assume I've messed up something in my code that explains why my many-to-many relation doesn't work.

I retrieve these two entities by generating (in Netbeans 9.0) 'Restful Web Services from Entity classes'. This way I can use these services to retrieve all attributes succesfully, except Collection with @ManyToMany annotation is always empty.

Any idea why it is not woking appreciated. It is first time trying this, so pardon me for any dumm mistakes.

**Person class:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TJV_5_PERSON")
@XmlRootElement
public class Person implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "PID")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "PNAME")
    private String name;

    @ManyToMany()
    @JoinTable(
        name = "TJV_5_SERIE_2_PERSON",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "PID", referencedColumnName = "PID"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "SID", referencedColumnName = "SID")
    )
        // always empty
    private Collection<Serie> favourites = new ArrayList<Serie>();

    public Person() {
    }

    public Person(Integer id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @XmlTransient
    public Collection<Serie> getFavourites() {
        return favourites;
    }

    public void setFavourites(Collection<Serie> favourites) {
        this.favourites = favourites;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 5;
        hash = 31 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.id);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj) {
            return true;
        }
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        final Person other = (Person) obj;
        if (!Objects.equals(this.id, other.id)) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Person{" + "id=" + id + ", name=" + name + ", favourites=" + favourites + '}';
    }

}
```

**Serie class:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TJV_5_SERIE")
@XmlRootElement
public class Serie implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "SID")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "STITLE")
    private String title;

    // always empty
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "favourites")
    private Collection<Person> fans = new ArrayList<Person>();

    public Serie() {
    }

    public Serie(Integer id, String title) {
        this.id = id;
        this.title = title;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    @XmlTransient
    public Collection<Person> getFans() {
        return fans;
    }

    public void setFans(Collection<Person> fans) {
        this.fans = fans;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 3;
        hash = 67 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.id);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj) {
            return true;
        }
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        final Serie other = (Serie) obj;
        if (!Objects.equals(this.id, other.id)) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Serie{" + "id=" + id + ", title=" + title + ", fans=" + fans + '}';
    }

}
```

Comment: In ORM code the object model should rule. The `id` column in a table is a performance hack and not an inherent part of an object model. Object comparison should rest on the modeled attributes that distinguish individuals. If you don't have such attributes that indicates an incomplete model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not 100% sure, but you may not retrieving any results beacuse of @XMLTransiet annotation above the Serie.class method

```
@XmlTransient
public Collection<Person> getFans() {
    return fans;
}
```

Try to look in documentation https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlTransient.html or in connected posts [Hide an entity variable from xml message - @XmlTransient not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18603517/hide-an-entity-variable-from-xml-message-xmltransient-not-working)

Comment: Removing @XmlTransient annotation at getFans() in Serie.class works only for Serie.class. Method getFans() starts returning correct results. However the other side of the many-to-many, Collection at Person.class is still empty. Thank you very much for that, at least something is working.

Answer (score 0):

The other issue is cascading data between two corresponding @ManyToMany tables. It means that you have intersection and the data appears in this table automatically when you use some type of cascade but you need send a POST request. It means in your service class layer you can create a method responsible for creating Person and assign a Serie to this Person object which is a foreign key. The article about cascading is here :) https://vladmihalcea.com/a-beginners-guide-to-jpa-and-hibernate-cascade-types/